# Perguntas com recompensas sem respostas

Tags: debate, perguntas-sem-resposta

Pela primeira vez enfrento esta situação: Preciso muito resolver um problema, no qual achei poucas referências sobre o assunto e as quais são superficiais. Especialmente uma dúvida que ofereci recompensa no SOen sobre testes de interface e Jenkins.
Apesar disso, a pergunta teve poucas visualizações e **nenhum** comentário.
 Como proceder nestes casos? Devo considerar outra solução para o meu problema?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer quando uma pergunta não teve respostas nem comentários para orientação, mesmo sendo oferecido recompensa?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/3117)

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871379/ui-tests-with-jenkins-and-casperjs e no SOpt http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69421/testes-de-interface-automatizados-com-o-jenkins

Comment: Se for software que existe no Github por exemplo podes colocar a pergunta lá como um _issue_, ou então procurar um grupo no google que muitas vezes há.